# dimensions and position of overflow element with css

Tags: html, css, position, flexbox

I'll start with the code and image which will make it easier to explain what I want to achieve and the problems I'm facing.

```css
 body,
 html {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
 }
 .container {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid black;
 }
 .topPanel {
   flex-grow: 1;
   background-color: green;
 }
 .bottomPanel {
   padding: 10px 0px;
   position: relative;
   background-color: black;
 }
 .bottomPanel .alert {
   position: relative;
   top: -35px;
   background-color: grey;
   text-align: center;
 }
 .bottomPanel .message {
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="topPanel"></div>
  <div class="bottomPanel">
    <div class="alert">
      alert
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      message
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

([code in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xpyp1zj/))

#### How it looks:

[image]

The `topPanel` occupies most of the height of the container, and the `bottomPanel` can vary in it's height.

The `alert` element needs to have the width of the `bottomPanel` and be exactly above it (in the code/image there's a gap between them but that's just to show that it's above it, the gap shouldn't be there).
The `alert` height can also vary, and the height shouldn't be hardcoded but in relation to the `bottomPanel`.

The `alert` is in both aspects of logic and semantics should be a child of `bottomPanel` and not the `topPanel`.

The problem I'm facing is that with `position: relative` the height of `topPanel` includes the height of `alert` even though it overflows.
If I add `overflow` then the `alert` isn't visible.
If I change to `position: absolute` then the width of the `alert` isn't extended and `width: 100%` will make it have the width of the `container` and not the parent element.

Any ideas how I can make it work with only css?
I thought of maybe using flex here as well, but thought that maybe someone will have a better idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `.bottomPanel` it's own flex-container, add `position:relative`.

Then the `.alert` can be:

```
.bottomPanel .alert {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 100%;
}
```

---

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
}
.topPanel {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}
.bottomPanel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}
.bottomPanel .alert {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 100%;
  color: white;
}
.bottomPanel .message {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="topPanel"></div>
  <div class="bottomPanel">
    <div class="alert">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, voluptatum.
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis consequatur enim laboriosam excepturi ex nulla dolorum vitae, officia sapiente, laborum? Possimus eius odio, recusandae tempora, soluta harum minus consequatur quibusdam, blanditiis
      in voluptatum sit laborum!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `alert` part needs to be on top of the `topPanel` when it renders, it needs to overflow on top of the `message`.

Comment: Nice! this works well.  I tried this approach, I guess that what made the difference was setting `box-sizing: border-box` to all elements. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- set `bottom:0` in your `bottomPanel`
- give `padding:10px 0` to `.alert`
- reset `line-height`

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.topPanel {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: green;
}
.bottomPanel {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
.bottomPanel .alert {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.bottomPanel .message {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="topPanel"></div>
  <div class="bottomPanel">
    <div class="alert">
      alert
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      message
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One problem remains, that the `bottomPanel` has the height of both the children's height, I need it to have the exact height of `message`

Comment: @NitzanTomer not quiet sure of what you mean, but see updated answer

Comment: This is better, as what I meant is that the `alert` needs to look like it's over the 'topPanel` (for example if the `alert` background is semi-transparent you'll see the `topPanel` under it).  The problem is that the height of the `bottomPanel` should equal the height of the `message`, but here the height/padding/bottom attributes of the `alert` seem to affect it

Comment: If I understand correctly you need to change HTML markup for that

Comment: Right, that I already had, but the thing is that the `alert` element is the child of the `bottomPanel` (logically and semantically) but only appear on top. This example is a simplified example of my real scenario. The best I've managed to get to the right answer is to use `position: absolute` on the `alert` but then it seems that I can't match the width of the `bottomPanel` with css only

Comment: @NitzanTomer see my updated answer withone of my revisions using`position:absolute` (that you didn't see, because I updated to change HTML markup)

Comment: Thanks, this works well. I accepted the other answer as I prefer the `position: absolute` along with `bottom: 100%` over the `line-height = 1`. But other than that it's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again